# Check if user exist in AD using Azure CLI

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-cli

I have installed the Azure CLI to connect to the tenant.
Now I want to import a CSV containing several emails to get cross checked if they exist in the AD.

There a tons of ways to do it with 'Get-ADUser' (which I'm not using since I'd need to set up the server locally) but I could not find any with Azure CLI.

Anyone managed to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This is the list of commands to manage users with AZ CLI
[image: az ad user]
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/user?view=azure-cli-latest

Also, there is a PowerShell module that allows you to manage the user in your [Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0).
[image: Azure Users]
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0#users

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the ad users by using below command:

```
Get-AzureADUser -All $true
```

[image]

If you want to know if the user exists or not follow below commands:
XX- example display name

Step-1

```
   $s= Get-AzureADUser -All $true
```

Step-2

```
if($s.DisplayName -eq "XX")
{
Write-Host "Present"
} else
{
Write-Host "Not Present"
}
```

[image]

**References taken from:**

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azaduser?view=azps-8.3.0#syntax